# Why won't my website show up in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flash

Can someone look at my [site](http://www.stouffvillechristmashometour.ca) on IE and look at my code through view source and let me know what I am doing wrong.

My site shows up on Firefox, but only shows my pink background in IE all my content is missing. I spoke to my hosting company and they think its comparability issue but their are reasons I don't believe that.

1. My site was up and running 40 minutes before I changed the text size and a few images.
2. I haven't changed any major coding that I know of to make my website a compatability issue.

Its a basic website but I need my site to run in IE. I would put my code up here but its too long. Also when I look at my website through Dreamweaver preview it also only shows me the pink background in IE.

Comment: which version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You opened an html comment under the script tag but never closed it.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
```

Close it as follows:

```
 -->
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you DarkXphenomenom :) sometimes little things like that i miss cause im over looking everything. It works perfect now.